# Column is not iterable in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, we are a bit puzzled. In Jupyter Notebook we have the following data frame:

```
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+ 
|          created_at|created_at_int|  screen_name|            hashtags|ht_count|     single_hashtag|
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672001|     texanraj|  [containers, cool]|       1|         containers|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672001|     texanraj|  [containers, cool]|       1|               cool|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672002|   hubskihose|[automation, future]|       1|         automation|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672002|   hubskihose|[automation, future]|       1|             future|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672002|    IBMDevOps|            [DevOps]|       1|             devops|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672003|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|       voiceofwipro|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672003|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|              cloud|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672003|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|             leader|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672003|SoumitraKJana|      [Cloud, Cloud]|       1|              cloud|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672003|SoumitraKJana|      [Cloud, Cloud]|       1|              cloud|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672004|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|       voiceofwipro|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672004|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|              cloud|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672004|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|managedfiletransfer|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672004|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|         asaservice|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672004|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|   interconnect2017|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672004|SoumitraKJana|[VoiceOfWipro, Cl...|       1|                hmi|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672005|SoumitraKJana|[Cloud, ManagedFi...|       1|              cloud|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672005|SoumitraKJana|[Cloud, ManagedFi...|       1|managedfiletransfer|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672005|SoumitraKJana|[Cloud, ManagedFi...|       1|         asaservice|
|2017-03-05 00:00:...|    1488672005|SoumitraKJana|[Cloud, ManagedFi...|       1|   interconnect2017|
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+
only showing top 20 rows

root
 |-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at_int: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hashtags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- ht_count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- single_hashtag: string (nullable = true)
```

We are trying to get the count of hashtags per hour. The approach we are taking is to use Window to partition by `single_hashtag`. Something like this:

```
# create WindowSpec                                 
hashtags_24_winspec = Window.partitionBy(hashtags_24.single_hashtag). \  
            orderBy(hashtags_24.created_at_int).rangeBetween(-3600, 3600)
```

However, when we try to do the sum of the `ht_count` column using:

```
#sum_count_over_time = sum(hashtags_24.ht_count).over(hashtags_24_winspec)
```

we get the following error:

```
Column is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 240, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

The error message is not very informative and we are puzzled, which column exactly to investigate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using wrong `sum`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

sum_count_over_time = sum(hashtags_24.ht_count).over(hashtags_24_winspec)
```

In practice you'll probably want alias or package import:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as sql_sum

# or

from pyspark.sql.functions as F
F.sum(...)
```

Comment: Wow, that was a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing out the obvious!